# While loop using Scanner

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hi I am writing a program that uses Scanner to get input from a user and then uses a boolean method to check if the input is up to six characters in length. The problem is that, I used a while loop to keep asking for input if the length is less than six; but after the first wrong input, if you insert a string of six letters or longer, the loop still continues. Please here is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordChecker{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input;


  System.out.println("Enter a password");
  input = kbd.nextLine();

  boolean result = LengthCheck(input);

  LengthCheck(input);
  while(result == false){
   System.out.println("Please enter a minimum password of six characters");
   input = kbd.nextLine();

  }


  System.out.println(input);
  System.out.println(result);


  }//close main

  public static boolean LengthCheck(String input){

    boolean result = false;
    int length = 6;

    if(input.length() >= length){
      result = true;
    }

    return result;
  }//LengthCheck

}//PasswordChecker
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In you scenario, you want to exit the loop when the password is more than six characters long. Thus you need to make sure you are checking that condition in your `while` statement.

This will do the trick for you:

```
while(LengthCheck(input) == false){
    System.out.println("Please enter a minimum password of six characters");
    input = kbd.nextLine();
}
```

The loop will continue to go-around until `LengthCheck` is satisfied you've entered a password of 6 digits.

Comment: @user2932716 Glad to help - You can remove any other calls to `LengthCheck` there were two above the loop in your example code above, these are not required.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check `LengthCheck()` inside the while loop ,try this

```
while(result == false){
        System.out.println("Please enter a minimum password of six characters");
        input = kbd.nextLine();
     ->   result = LengthCheck(input);

    }
```